# Google Play Game Services in China?

Tags: google-play-games, great-firewall-of-china

I have understood that due to some laws there are some telecommunications services blocked in China.

Can developers expect the Google Play Game Services being available to Chinese users?

**EDIT: This question is about Google Play Game Services used primarily for programming.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we known,almost all of google services are located in us which are block by China G.F.W .In China, only the google.com.hk can be visited directly without using VPN.

Comment: My partner say : "I tested it out, it doesn't quite connect properly without VPN but with a VPN it works with no problems, so it will be fine."